# How do you enumerate users that belong to a given group or SID in C?

Tags: c, authorization, msdn

Given a group name say 'administrators' I need to get a list of all users in that group.

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375742%28v=VS.85%29.aspx and I do not see a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

[NetGroupGetUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370430.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand the question when looking at the link, but you may want to look into WMI.  I never used it from C, but from C# it was quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sample code will help you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180907%28VS.80%29.aspx#Y456